# Django, queryset, filter today

Tags: python, django, date, django-queryset

I'm trying to query the database and get the entries for today. So I got a model **Events** with a date time field. Just to clarify, if I remove the date filter, it does return entries from the database. If I add them it does not. I double-checked that there is an item for today.

views.py

```
def dashboard(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        events_today = Event.objects.filter(date__year=now.year, date__month=now.month, date__day=now.day)
        return render_to_response("dashboard.html", {'today': events_today,},  RequestContext(request))
```

**Update**
It does work if I change the `USE_TZ` to `False` in `settings.py`. But it doesn't if it's `True`.
**Update 2**
I even uploaded the project to my VPS just in case it had something to do with my computer but still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `datetime.datetime.now()` use [`timezone.now()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now):

```
from django.utils import timezone

timezone.now()
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I forgot to change `USE_TZ` to `True` and that's why it worked. So it still doesn't for `USE_TZ=False`. Any ideas?

Comment: Using pdb i'm getting: `(Pdb) now = datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 28, 3, 5, 35, 350410, tzinfo=<UTC>)` and `(Pdb) events_today = []`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can try this query:

```
events_today = Event.objects.filter(date=datetime.datetime.today())
```